# There should be no spaces inside this paren

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have the following function that i'm using for removing classnames. I'm getting the following error with eslint which i'm not sure how to resolve because I need the space in there to replace it. Can I escape this or something with regx?

`There should be no spaces inside this paren  space-in-parens`

```
function removeClass(elem, className) {
   let newClass = ` ${elem.className.replace( /[\t\r\n]/g, ' ')} `

   if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
        while (newClass.indexOf(` ${className} `) >= 0 ) {
             newClass = newClass.replace(` ${className} `, ' ')
        }
        elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should remove spaces on line 2  `replace( /` and on line 5  `>= 0 )`

Comment: @styopdev that solved my issue, i wrongly assumed it was the space in the single quotes but you are 100% correct thank you!

Comment: Simpler way to achieve the same: `function removeClass(el, cl) { el.className = el.className.split(' ').filter(i => i !== null && i !== cl).join(' ') }`